# How to 'fix' gnuclient after opening a second instance of emacs?

Tags: emacsclient

If I open a second instance of emacs accidentally (which happens more often than I am willing to admit) and then close it, `gnuclient` starts responding with the following error:

```
gnuclient: Connection refused
gnuclient: unable to connect to local
```

Is there a way to fix this without closing the original instance of emacs and then reopening it?  Sometimes this is very disruptive, and I've grown quite dependent upon `gnuclient`.

Perhaps I should be using `emacsclient` instead?  I see that it continues sending files to the original instance (on which the server was started) and is not affected by the start of a second instance.

Perhaps `emacsclient` should be my default editor rather than `emacs`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you write about gnuclient settings (such as gnuserv, gnuserv-start, etc) in your init file and your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `emacsclient`. As far as I know it's now preferred way to
edit files with already running Emacs instance rather than open new instance
of Emacs.

I myself use this:

```
;; Start Emacs server.

(require 'server)

(unless (server-running-p)
  (server-start))
```

Here, when server is not already running (i.e. you started first Emacs
instance) it's started. When you accidentally start second Emacs instance
`server-running-p` is evaluated to `t` and `server-start` is not called. So,
it's safe to start more Emacsen without the fear to break something.

Once this is running, you should use `emacsclient` program to edit
files. This will open them in “server” Emacs instance.

I used to have this alias in shell:

```
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

# …

export EDITOR='emacsclient'
alias e='emacsclient'
```

But now I usually use EShell from Emacs itself, where I have another alias:

```
alias e find-file $1
```

So, I don't need to use `emacsclient` often. It's still useful in some
cases, though. For example I'm typing this in Emacs, in temporary markdown
file created by “It's All Text” Firefox plugin that uses `emacsclient` to
tell Emacs that I want to edit the file.